# Need to find Property name

Tags: visual-studio

I have several tables in my application that are displaying lists of objects from classes. I have properties to represent each value in those classes as defined in the following example

```
...
Public Property Cod() As Int32
        Get
            Return _codigo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Int32)
          _codigo = value
        End Set
    End Property
...
```

My code hides every column and then, I use the "formatarCol" method to state which columns I want shown represented as the second parameter(which must have the same name as the properties mentioned above) and the name to be displayed for that column as the third parameter.

```
...
Utilidades.formatarCol(.Columns, "Cod", "Cod")
Utilidades.formatarCol(.Columns, "Estab", "Estabelecimento")
Utilidades.formatarCol(.Columns, "Sel", "Sel.")
...
```

Everything is working fine but I was trying to rename some of the properties. If I rename said properties I have to go to each table and manually change each string. I can't just use a replace all because different classes may have properties with the same name.
I was hoping that someone had a suggestion on how to get the Property's name instead of manually adding a string so that if I need to rename a Property again I won't have to manually go through every column where it's used and change the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the name of a property in a `class` you can use `NameOf`

Example:

```
NameOf([Namespace to class].Cod) //returns "Cod"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename property via refactor:
Right click your property in code -> Refactor -> Rename

It will only rename property for your class and for all occurrences of that property.

Comment: The problem is that in 
    Utilidades.formatarCol(.Columns, "Estab", "Estabelecimento")
the property is being referenced as a string, There is no Property.Name or similar system that I can use to replace it.